# Will water flowing directly downwards hydrate my farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm living on an island and trying to play with all the constraints that entails - foremost being a lack of space to build things. I want to create a farm so I don't need to rely on mob spawns for my food but the lack of island space means I'll need to build my farm upwards rather than outwards.

If I were to create a series of 5x5 "shelves" of farmland on top of each other and connect them with a hole in the center would water flowing from the topmost layer of farmland hydrate the shelves beneath it?

From my experience I know that flowing water will hydrate tilled dirt it flows adjacent to, but I'm not sure if the situation is the same when the water flows straight downward.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes. Confirmed experimentally.

[image]

Comment: How many source blocks, just the top one?

Comment: @Yates Yes, between the redstone lamps so that it wouldn't spill sideways, just "leak" downwards.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I didn't know this.

Comment: @Yates Flowing water hydrates just the same as water sources. This is useful in some modpacks where vanilla buckets are unobtainable and classic water generation is disabled - you can dig "irrigation channels" off a lake leaving 8 blocks of farmland in between them and it will be hydrated in 9x9 from the "tip" of the channels.